# css z-index not working in 2 different child

Tags: css, z-index

i'm here to ask your help again, this is my problem:

[image]

The top of my web site (blue) is a section with position:relative and the same is about me section (white), my problem is that the macbook appear in the about me section, if i set z-index for top (z-index 10) and z-index for about me (z-index 20) but problem persist.

If you want to see code, i have uploaded the site to matteoterzi.it

Thank you in advice.

--EDIT--

The html code is this:

```
 <section id="top">
        <div class="bg-effect">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- top row -->
                <div class="row top-row"></div>


                <!-- middle row -->
                <div class="row middle-row"></div>

                <!-- last row, with macbook pro iphone and headphones -->
                <div class="row bottom-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img src="./img/macbookpro.png" class="img-responsive macbookpro">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-2">
                        <img src="./img/iphone_back.png" class="img-responsive iphone_back">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="about-me">
        <div class="bg-effect">
            <h1>About Me</h1>
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                        <img src="img/me.jpg" class="img-responsive me">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And this is the css

```
section#top {
    background-color: #1ac6ff;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
section#top .bg-effect {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 0 0 200px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3) inset;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

section#top .container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
section#top .top-row {
    margin-top: -85px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
section#top .middle-row {
    margin-top: 15vh;
}
section#top .bottom-row:last-child {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid;
    bottom: -50px;
}
/* ipad fix */

section#top .top-row .ipad_black_up {
    position: relative;
    top: -130px;
}
/* iphone fix */

section#top .bottom-row .iphone_back {
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    bottom: -90px;
    z-index: 0;
}
/* hdd fix */

section#top .middle-row .hdd {
    margin-top: 60px;
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
}
/* contact and see my blog button */

section#top .button-row {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
section#top .button-row .button a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.10);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    transition-duration: 0.7s;
}
section#top .button-row .button a:hover {
    border: 2px solid #f8806d;
}
section#top .button-row .fill:hover {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
section#top .button-row .fill:hover {
    color: whitesmoke;
}
section#top .button-row .fill:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: #f8806d;
    border: 2px solid #f8806d;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-in;
}
section#top .button-row .fill:before a {
    color: #1ac6ff;
}
section#top .button-row .fill:hover:before {
    top: 0;
}

section#about-me {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    color: #26262a;
}
section#about-me .bg-effect {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at what your HTML and CSS are? Post a complete code example *in your question* please.

Comment: Links to other sites are not recommended, because those sites may change at any moment and then won't match the problem in the question any more. Is it possible to post the relevant code in the question, as a snippet?

Comment: @MrLister yes no problem, I thought it was easier with the site because if i post code you could not see the image

Comment: **[Please write a Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: Anyway, if the problem is that the image is visible behind the lower section, that is because the lower section has a transparent background. Changing the background to white would solve the issue.

Comment: So, the z-index was ok... sorry for the inconvenience. @MrLister

Answer (score 0):

Man, you can just use `overflow-y: hidden` in the section you don't want to be over the "About Me".

```css
section#top .container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```